# WebPages / WebMatrix - How not to apply PageStart on a page?

Tags: asp.net-webpages

I have these pages:

1. _PageStart.cshtml
2. Index.cshtml
3. Login.cshtml

   .

   .

   .

n. OtherPage.cshtml

Basically, I want to restrict a user from accessing all the pages when he is not logged in, with one exception, "Login.cshtml".

In my "_PageStart.cshtml", when a user is not logged in, the page is redirected to "Login.cshtml". Since "Login.cshtml" is requested, the "_Pagestar.cshtml" will run and will detect that the user is not logged in, as result, an infinite redirect will be created.

The question now is:

1. Is "_PageStart.cshtml" the best place to put the redirect?
2. If the answer in question one is yes, then how not to apply PageStart on a specific page?
3. If the answer in question one is no, then where? Should I create a helper and put it in every page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the pages you want to protect inside of a different folder and title it something like 'Members'. In this folder place your _PageStart.cshtml with the following code:

```
@{ 
    WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
}
```

If you are using the standard directory structure illustrated in the Starter Site then your Login.cshtml should be in the Account directory and the WebSecurity helper will automatically redirect users back to your Login.cshtml page if they try to access your protected directory without authenticating their membership.

Jerrod

Comment: sorry for the so-late-reply. I found your answer useful per directory level, the problem occurs when in that folder, there are restricted and non-restricted files. Is there any other way without restructuring my directories?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser() code from the _PageStart.cshtml file and place it individually in each individual page you wish to restrict.

Comment: I guess that's my only option.

Comment: You could probably put the call to WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); inside an "if" block.  Basically, if the page is NOT Login.cshtml then call WebSecurity.RequreAuthenticateduser();

Comment: @SteveJ I like this solution, I've used it many times. No need for code duplication, it's a waste of space and time.

Comment: Inside the Layout.cshtml file for that directory, you could do a `switch` to determine the Page being requested by the browser and decide whether or not to insert a `WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser` into that page. This would be a cleaner option and not so repetitive. #Edit number 2: Oops, I just noticed @SteveJ's comment.